# Recommendation for series protection resistors on CAN bus?

Tags: can, circuit-protection

When implementing an RS-485 interface, I tend to follow TI's recommendation in the [SN65HVD75 datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn65hvd75.pdf) to include \$10 \Omega\$ series resistors on the A and B lines.  The TVS diodes I'm using clamp at 15 V maximum, and the transceiver can handle up to 16.5 V, but I prefer some design margin.  The comms are enclosed in a large, metal enclosure, and do not interface outside of it.

[image: SN65HVD75 datasheet]

As a carry-over, I have been including series resistors on CAN bus interfaces, right at the driver/receiver pins.  This bus also resides in the enclosure and does not interface outside of it.  The TVS diodes clamp at 8 V maximum and the transceiver I'm using can tolerate up to 16 V on the H/L lines.

Given this much higher margin it would seem that series resistors are unnecessary, but I am still hesitant to remove them from the design.  Being only \$10 \Omega\$, they won't drop too much voltage (~250 mV of 3.3 V; high/low input thresholds are 2 V, 0.8 V, respectively).  Yet, out of [four](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn65hvd230.pdf) [sample](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/TJA1057.pdf) CAN transceivers from [different](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/NCV7344-D.PDF) [manufacturers](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/ATA6560-ATA6561-High-Speed-CAN-Transceiver-DS20005991A.pdf) none of them recommend series protection resistors, either.  Should I just leave them down or is there a strong reason to remove them?

**EDIT:** The CAN bus also interfaces with a user interface board, which drives an LCD screen on the outside of the enclosure.

Comment: You should first identify the *existing* dangers before applying precautions: *The comms are enclosed in a large, metal enclosure, and do not interface outside of it.* So, what can happen? If transmitter and receiver are really inside a metal enclosure, you don't need to worry about ESD (provided that during production, measures against ESD are taken), the enclose may act as cage of Faraday, such that you neither need to worry about surge transients.

Comment: @Huisman True, but I neglected to mention the CAN bus extends to a user interface board that drives an LCD, which does get tested for ESD events.  Also, in production and service these boards are handled by humans possibly without proper ESD mitigation.

Comment: "Also, in production and service these boards are handled by humans possibly without proper ESD mitigation." That seems rather unreasonable, no? Far more than just the CAN inputs are at risk in that case. Everything on the PCB is vulnerable and a little ESD protection the CAN inputs isn't going to make any difference.

Comment: What is the practical reason for "removing" 2 resistors from your design? If they are already placed/routed then keep them. Manufacturer's recommendation are (usually) intended to build the most reliable circuit using their own chipset, they've most likely tested it and found it necessary for the particular case scenario you highlighted (which is about limiting current latching, not voltage). It surely won't hurt to have them. You could also contact TI, describe your setup and talk trade-offs about removing these resistors, if that's worth your time.

Comment: @DKNguyen I've seen it before where the board is assembled by CMs with proper ESD protection, put into an enclosure, and sent off to another supplier that puts the assembly into a larger assembly with wire harnessing. The second supplier usually has more lax ESD requirements, and I've seen issues with ESD at this second step.  Since it's above my paygrade to do anything about the supply chain, at least I can shore up protection on the board.

Comment: @Cisco25 Mostly BOM consolidation and size reduction (read: cost).  I'm constantly optimizing the design so I like to visit every component with a magnifying glass.  There are several separate buses inter- and intra-board so two resistors times several transceivers times production quantities equals more than a drop in a bucket.

Comment: @calcium3000 1000 pcs = $8.4 saving. Is it worth potential line-down / customer return situations? What application is this circuit for? If you really want to remove them, what don't you give it a shot of applying a higher voltage on your bus and see if the transceiver inputs are latching or not with and without the resistors? Validate on few boards and here you got your a conclusive proof for your initial question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the response from a TI representative:

> Even though RS-485 and CAN drivers look very similar they actually behave differently. For RS-485 both the A and B pins are driven high and low, whereas for CAN the CANH and CANL pins are only driven high. Then the termination resistor is used to recess the signal back to the recessive voltage. Because of this CAN devices are designed to specifically to drive a 60 ohm load (2 120 ohm termination resistors in parallel). This is because typical CAN cabling has an impedance of 60 ohms. Any other resistance may affect the effectiveness of the CAN driver and the ability for the termination resistors to dampen any reflections in the cabling. Keep in mind that for this device the maximum load that it can drive is 50 ohms.
>
> In your case, [the series 10 \$\Omega\$ resistors] are pretty small and they only increase the termination resistance by a small amount so they are most likely fine. As long as the resistance doesn't exceed the maximum driving capability of this device (50 ohms). Howeverc, this device was designed to be used with 120 ohm termination and the extra resistance is not necessary and may hurt the performance of the device.

So it sounds like the resistors, if small enough in value, can be used without adversely affecting the transceiver's behavior.  But I plan to remove them or replace them with 0 \$\Omega\$ jumpers in future designs.

Comment: That quote is misleading. The CANL pin is only driven low or not driven. The CANH pin is driven high or not driven. The cable impedance is 120 ohm dIfferential. The driver has to drive two 120 ohm terminations (one at each end) that's why it needs to drive 60 ohm, not because the cable impedance is 60 ohm.

Answer (score 2):

I never saw series resistors in CAN Networks but the usage of a common mode choke instead (e.g. DLW43SH101XK2#) together with a split termination of 60R + 60R + 4.7nF. (e.g. TJA1057 Datasheet Fig 8 on Page 14). The common mode choke is for EMI compliance at high baudrates. Sometimes I see additionally protection by a Varistor (e.g. B72500E2170S160) to GND on CAN_H and CAN_L.